# Git error on Pull "error: unable to find ....."

Tags: git, version-control

I have stuck on getting the following error.

```
error: unable to find c52abdb1a42b8ed7b026d87e4a5881a396d96fc7
fatal: object c52abdb1a42b8ed7b026d87e4a5881a396d96fc7 not found
```

It have occur by pushing from my local repository with

```
git push origin master
```

and the error were prompted on the remote repository after pulling with

```
git pull
```

How such errors are resolved?

Note: Both local and remote repos. are on Linux.

Cheers!

Comment: what is original? did you mean 
`git push origin master`?

Comment: yes, it's a typo sorry, I've fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how this error's generated. Yet I resolved it by executing the following command at the client who cause the error.

```
git revert HEAD
```

afterward a fresh commit where pushed to the remote repository by the same client.

Cheers!